# Logistic Regression; I got the following error : 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

Trying to do a logistic regression for my graduation

```
y = df2.loc[:, df2.columns == 'FLAG_RESPOSTA']

os = SMOTE(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
columns = X_train.columns
os_data_X,os_data_y=os.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
os_data_X = pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_X,columns=columns )
os_data_y= pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_y,columns=['FLAG_RESPOSTA'])
# we can Check the numbers of our data
print("A Nova Amostra Tem Tamanho Igual a: ",len(os_data_X))
print("Número de Clientes que nao adquiriram: ",len(os_data_y[os_data_y['FLAG_RESPOSTA']==0]))
print("Número de Clientes que adquiriram:",len(os_data_y[os_data_y['FLAG_RESPOSTA']==1]))
print("Proporção de Clientes que nao adquiriram: ",len(os_data_y[os_data_y['FLAG_RESPOSTA']==0])/len(os_data_X))
print("Proporção de Clientes que adquiriram: ",len(os_data_y[os_data_y['FLAG_RESPOSTA']==1])/len(os_data_X))
```

And got the following error

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Provide desired output and please translate everything to English.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis I do not understand how translating the text strings in the print statements would help in correcting the error. Would you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue. `imbalanced-learn` works with Numpy column vectors for the `y` response vector.

Try:

```
import numpy as np
os_data_X,os_data_y=os.fit_resample(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))
```

Note also that it seems that `fit_sample` has been deprecated for `fit_resample` according to the module source code.